# How to get the value of an input element directly in the twig template

Tags: html, forms, symfony, twig

I have this form in my twig template:

```
<form id="search-box" action="/search" method="get">
    <input id="search-query" type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="search" role="textbox">
    <a id="search-btn" href="....."></a>
</form>
```

My goal is to use the value of the input **id="search-query"** to create the href for the **a id="search-btn"**

For this, I have to access the value of the input **id="search-query"**.

I have tryed:

```
{{ form.search-query.value }}
```

and

```
{{ search-box.search-query.value }}
```

But none of those works. I am getting the error that form or search does not exists.

Any idea?

Comment: What does your form type looks like ?

Comment: In addition to @iamdto question - is your form even built using Form component?

Comment: @thecatontheflat, no, the only thng in which concerns the form is the form html tag. This form is built directly in the twig file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you can do this with jQuery:

```
var given_val = '';
var wanted_href = '';
given_val = $('input#search-query').val();
wanted_href = 'http://www.example.com/' + given_val;
$('a#search-btn').attr('href',wanted_href);
```

Comment: Thank you, but i would like to use directly twig, not jquery.

Comment: `{{ form#search-query.value }}` - what is this? Does Twig support such syntax?

Comment: @thecatontheflat, no, twig does not support this syntax !

Comment: That's why I ASKED if those are css selectors! Please read before giving -1. Jesus!

Comment: Edit your answer, I'll remove it ;)

Comment: You're right @Jonur, I am on the client side in the twig template, so there is no possibility to access this variable without client side execution code as jquery.

Answer (score 1):

you should use `{{ form.search-query.all.value }}`

Comment: No, I am getting that the variable form does not exists.

Comment: it has to be an instance of FormView

Comment: cause I assume you are using Symfony2 forms

Comment: That's what I am trying to do now. Before, when I asked the auestion, I haven't used Symfony2 forms, but only the html form tag directly.